# Can overflow: hidden; be used to hide unpositioned content but still reveal positioned content?

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

First of all, take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Udvgm/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="tooWide">
        <p>This is just way too wide! We should clip it.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="relativeParent">
        <div id="absoluteChild">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container2">
    <p>This is some text which should be overlapped.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    background: grey;
    width: 450px;
}
#relativeParent{
    height: 40px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}

#absoluteChild{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: blue;
}
#tooWide {
    background: red;
    width: 600px;
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible for the blue box (#absoluteChild) to overflow outside the grey box (#container), but the overflowing parts of the red box (#tooWide) to be hidden.

Before you suggest it, using `overflow: hidden; overflow-y: visible;` (or `overflow-x: hidden; overflow: visible;`) causes the browser to throw in some unwanted scrollbars.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Udvgm/1/

Comment: Imagine that #tooWide represents any number of user-authored content elements of arbitrary width and #relativeParent is a child of one of those elements. We can't wrap #tooWide in anything special because we can't uniquely identify it (except with javascript).

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but I think you have an impossible set of requirements.

Comment: Ya, that is essentially the question: is it possible? Thanks anyway for looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible in your circumstances.

> Before you suggest it, using `overflow: hidden; overflow-y: visible;`
>   (or `overflow-x: hidden; overflow: visible;`) causes the browser to
>   throw in some unwanted scrollbars.

[From the spec:](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x)

> The computed values of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are the same as
>   their specified values, except that some combinations with `visible`
>   are not possible: if one is specified as `visible` and the other is
>   `scroll` or `auto`, then `visible` is set to `auto`.

A helpful page with examples and a better explanation: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Answer (score 0):

When you have a block with `overflow: hidden` and a block with `position: absolute` inside of it, until block with overflow and all parents of absolute positioned block have `position: static`, the absolute positioned block won't be hidden.

I don't know that you want to do with your code, but if you want to position some block from the block with `overflow`, you can move positioning context outside of the block with `overflow`, so absolute positioned block would be visible and could be positioned around.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/Udvgm/3/